# snmptt not translating traps, even with translate_log_trap_oid=1

Tags: linux, networking, snmp, net-snmp

I am having some trouble configuring `snmptt` to properly translate snmp traps.

The following is a problem:

/etc/snmp/snmptt.conf reflects:

```
EVENT fgFmTrapIfChange .1.3.6.1.4.1.12356.101.6.0.1004 "Status Events" Critical
FORMAT $*
EXEC /usr/local/nagios/libexec/eventhandlers/submit_check_result $r "snmp_traps" 2 "$O: $+*" "$*"
SDESC

Trap is sent to the managing FortiManager if an interface IP is changed
Variables:
  1: fnSysSerial
  2: ifName
  3: fgManIfIp
  4: fgManIfMask
EDESC
```

when a trap is received, /var/log/messages reflects:

```
Sep  6 12:07:32 SNMPMANAGERHOST snmptrapd[15385]:
2012-09-06 12:07:32 <UNKNOWN>
[UDP:
[192.168.100.2]:162->[192.168.100.31]]:
#012.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 = Timeticks: (707253943) 81 days, 20:35:39.43
#011.1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0 = OID: .1.3.6.1.4.1.12356.101.6.0.1004
#011.1.3.6.1.4.1.12356.100.1.1.1.0 = STRING: FGTNNNNNNNNN
#011.1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1.10 = STRING: internal4
#011.1.3.6.1.4.1.12356.101.6.2.1.0 = IpAddress: 192.168.65.100
#011.1.3.6.1.4.1.12356.101.6.2.2.0 = IpAddress: 255.255.255.0

Sep  6 12:07:37 SNMPMANAGERHOST icinga:
EXTERNAL COMMAND:
PROCESS_SERVICE_CHECK_RESULT;
192.168.100.2;
snmp_traps;
2;
enterprises.12356.101.6.0.1004: enterprises.12356.100.1.1.1.0:FGTNNNNNNNNN ifName.10:internal4 enterprises.12356.101.6.2.1.0:192.168.65.100 enterprises.12356.101.6.2.2.0:255.255.255.0
```

Since the `icinga` entry reflects the `EXEC`, it's obvious there is no translations occurring by `snmptt`.

I have verified that `translate_log_trap_oid` and `net_snmp_perl_enable` is enabled in `snmptt.ini`

When using `--debug=1` to start `snmptt`, I see the following in the `--debugfile`:

```
********** Net-SNMP version 5.05 Perl module enabled **********
```

The main NET-SNMP version is reported as `NET-SNMP version: 5.5`.

What else can be done to verify that `snmptt` is configured properly to translate traps?

I have run `snmptt-net-snmp-test` to verify whatever net-snmp-perl version I have installed properly supports translations.  The output indicates it does.

```
/root/snmptt_1.3/snmptt-net-snmp-test --best_guess=2

SNMPTT Net-SNMP Test v1.0
(c) 2003 Alex Burger
http://snmptt.sourceforge.net

MIBS:RFC1213-MIB
best_guess: 2


Testing translateObj
********************

Testing: .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1, long_names=disabled, include_module=disabled
Test passed.  Result: sysDescr

Testing: .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1, long_names=disabled, include_module=enabled
Test passed.  Result: RFC1213-MIB::sysDescr

Testing: .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1, long_names=enabled, include_module=disabled
Test passed.  Result: .iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.system.sysDescr

Testing: .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1, long_names=enabled, include_module=enabled
Test passed.  Result: RFC1213-MIB::.iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.system.sysDescr

Testing: sysDescr, long_names=disabled, include_module=disabled
Test passed.  Result: .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1

Testing: RFC1213-MIB::sysDescr, long_names=disabled, include_module=disabled
Test passed.  Result: .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1

Testing: system.sysDescr, long_names=disabled, include_module=disabled
Test passed.  Result: .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1

Testing: RFC1213-MIB::system.sysDescr, long_names=disabled, include_module=disabled
Test passed.  Result: .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1

Testing: .iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.system.sysDescr, long_names=disabled, include_module=disabled
Test passed.  Result: .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1


Testing getType
***************

Testing: .1.3.6.1.2.1.4.1
Test passed.  Result: INTEGER

Testing: ipForwarding
Test passed.  Result: INTEGER


Testing Description
*******************
Test passed.  Result:
-------------------------------------------------
The indication of whether this entity is acting
as an IP gateway in respect to the forwarding of
datagrams received by, but not addressed to, this
entity.  IP gateways forward datagrams.  IP hosts
do not (except those source-routed via the host).
Note that for some managed nodes, this object may
take on only a subset of the values possible.
Accordingly, it is appropriate for an agent to
return a `badValue' response if a management
station attempts to change this object to an
inappropriate value.
-------------------------------------------------
```

I have manually gone through the MIB with the definition that's not resolving, and verified that it is properly linking back to the proper resolved definition.  It is:

```
FORTINET-FORTIGATE-MIB.txt contains:

fgFmTrapIfChange NOTIFICATION-TYPE
    OBJECTS     { fnSysSerial, ifName, fgManIfIp, fgManIfMask }
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "Trap is sent to the managing FortiManager if an interface IP is changed"
    ::= { fgFmTrapPrefix 1004 }


fgFmTrapPrefix OBJECT IDENTIFIER
    ::= { fgMgmt 0 }

fgMgmt OBJECT IDENTIFIER
    ::= { fnFortiGateMib 6 }

fnFortiGateMib
    ::= { fortinet 101 }

IMPORTS
    FnBoolState, FnIndex, fnAdminEntry, fnSysSerial, fortinet
        FROM FORTINET-CORE-MIB

fortinet MODULE-IDENTITY
    ::= { enterprises 12356 }

LOOKS GOOD!!!!!
1.3.6.1.4.1.12356.101.6.0.1004
```

I've exhausted all the documentation and even posted fruitlessly in the [snmptt-users mailing list.](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=29776714)

I can not prove it is the MIB.

Why would `snmptt` fail to translate traps?

Simply:

- $O = enterprises.12356.101.6.0.1004
- when $O should = fgFmTrapIfChange

Thanks,

Matt

***[UPDATE]***

[snmptt.ini](http://pastebin.com/EsXnL9Qq)

snmptrapd.conf:

```
authCommunity log,execute,net communitystr
traphandle default /usr/bin/snmptthandler
```

[snmptt.conf](http://pastebin.com/jFeXVarh)

[MIB where trap that isn't being translated lives](http://pastebin.com/8chVhXxH) (and it's [referenced MIB](http://pastebin.com/LFrSkc4g)).

Note that linkUp and linkDown are translating properly.

***[UPDATE 2]***

I have also tested with another MIB that isn't a default MIB contained within the net-snmp package, and this MIB also fails to resolve.

***[UPDATE 3]***

If I set the following in snmptt.ini:

`mode = standalone`

And I set the following in snmptrapd.conf:

`traphandle  default /usr/sbin/snmptt --ini=/etc/snmp/snmptt.ini`

I am able to translate traps as expected.

This means that whatever method `/usr/sbin/snmptt` uses to daemonize may not have access to the MIBs, or may be doing something other than what's described.  The documentation included within `snmptt.ini` likely will contain the answers I seek.

## [[ SOLUTION ]]

Set `mibs_environment = ALL` in `snmptt.ini`

Description:

```
# Allows you to set the MIBS environment variable used by SNMPTT
# Leave blank or comment out to have the systems enviroment settings used
# To have all MIBS processed, set to ALL
# See the snmp.conf manual page for more info.
```

`mibs_environment = ALL` must be set in `snmptt.ini` even with snmptrapd starting with `-m ALL` (where `ALL` is a wild card statement that includes all MIBs [defined within the files]).

\o.

Comment: Can you post your snmptt.ini? How are you starting snmptt?

Comment: original question updated with: snmptt. snmptrapd.conf snmptt.conf, trap MIB and MIB referenced for trap definition.

Comment: So, are you using nagios or icinga?  I haven't used icinga at all, but does it install utilities in /usr/local/nagios?

Comment: What utilities are you concerned with?  icinga and nagios are essentially the same thing.  My concern isn't with icinga alerting; as the passive services are configured and the pipe is functioning.  It is the script that pipes data into the FIFO that is the `command pipe` for icinga/nagios is not being provided with the correctly translated data.  This translated data is a result of `snmptt` translating the `OID` of received `traps`.

Comment: directly `/usr/local/nagios/libexec/eventhandlers/submit_check_result` exists and can be executed by `snmptt`.  See [my roll out document](http://mbrownnyc.wordpress.com/technology-solutions/reliability-monitoring-solution/part-4-sending-snmp-traps-to-icinga/).

Comment: The submit_check_result utility.  Your snmptt.conf is trying to exec /usr/local/nagios/libexec/eventhandlers/submit_check_result.  Now, I set up snmptt with nagios back in June, so the details are starting to get fuzzy.  Your configs look good (near as I can tell)and your logfiles contain data that is similar enough to mine.  I don't think nagios/icinga care about the trap being translated, just that specific oids are handed off to the eventhandler with the proper message.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4802/discussion-between-d-f-and-mbrownnyc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted this in the chat window awhile back, but it looks like you may have left it.  Your snmptt.ini file has the following translation options set :

```
translate_log_trap_oid = 1
translate_value_oids = 1
translate_enterprise_oid_format = 1
translate_trap_oid_format = 0
translate_varname_oid_format = 0
translate_integers = 1
```

The interesting one is the 'translate_trap_oid_format' which affects the value of $O.  Valid values are 0 - 4, with 0 turning off translation, the rest are listed in snmptt.ini --

```
Set to 0 to disable translating OID values to text (symbolic form)
Set to 1 to translate OID values to short text (symbolic form) (eg: BuildingAlarm)
Set to 2 to translate OID values to short text with module name (eg: UPS-MIB::BuildingAlarm)
Set to 3 to translate OID values to long text (eg: iso...upsAlarm.BuildingAlarm)
Set to 4 to translate OID values to long text with module name (eg:UPS-MIB::iso...upsAlarm.BuildingAlarm)
```

Comment: Ahh hah!  I knew it would be something trivial that I missed... always is! I will test tomorrow and award as necessary.  What's the deal with update 3 above?  Seems weird; but I guess it's a question for the dev(s).

Comment: That is odd.  I can only really offer guesses as to the reason for that behavior...that for some reason when its run standalone it ignores options in the .ini file.  It would probably take someone familiar with the source to answer that.

Comment: Believe it or not, this doesn't solve the problem.  However, referencing an old centreon installation, I was able to see that they use the standalone `mode` flag and feed the ini file in using `--ini=` as I had done in testing yesterday.  I'm hopeless in getting daemon mode to translate a MIB that doesn't come along with the net-snmp package.  I will just use the standalone method as it functions as I wish it to function.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Solution: `mibs_environment= ALL`. `# Allows you to set the MIBS environment variable used by SNMPTT
# Leave blank or comment out to have the systems enviroment settings used
# To have all MIBS processed, set to ALL
# See the snmp.conf manual page for more info`.  Works in daemon.  Alright!